# jQuery Validate Plugin invalid makes input disappear

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple form that requires an email to be confirmed, it works great if there are no errors.  But if I submit with errors jquery validation plugin is adding a display:none to the confirm-email input.  It does not add a invalid class not sure whats going on.

JS:

```
$("#customer-info").validate({
                         debug:true,
                         errorElement: "",
                         submitHandler: function(form) {
                             //TODO need a processing image
                             $.post(form.action, $(form).serialize(), function(result) {
                                 if(result > 0){
                                         // do some stuff
                                     }
                             },"json")
                             return false;
                         }
                });
```

html:

```
<form id="customer-info">
    <label for="customer-name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="customer-name" name="customer-name" placeholder="first last name" class="required" /><br />
        <label for="customer-email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="customer-email" name="customer-email" placeholder="email@gmail.com" class="required email" /><br />
        <label for="confirm-email">Confirm Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="confirm-email" name="confirm-email" placeholder="email@gmail.com" class="required email" equalTo="#customer-email" /><br />
        <label for="notes">Notes</label>
        <textarea id="notes" name="notes" placeholder="Any additional details or changes."></textarea><br />
        <center><input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn-go" /></center>
</form>
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine when I remove `debug: true` and `errorElement: ''`.

You break it when you define [`errorElement`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) as `''` (nothing).

By default, it's [`errorElement: 'label'`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/vHKha/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#customer-info").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            //TODO need a processing image
            $.post(form.action, $(form).serialize(), function(result) {
                if(result > 0){
                    // do some stuff
                }
            },"json")
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**Side note:**  You also may want to validate your HTML.  `<center></center>` has been deprecated for many years.

Comment: I removed the errorElement and added a custom errorPlacement to handle removing the error labels.  Thanks for the quick response and side tip.